# Neo4j Server running problems on Linux

Tags: linux, neo4j, tar

I am using Neo4j 2.0.3 Community server by installing it on my linux system (by unzipping the tar.gz). I got this error while I tried to start the server

> WARNING! You are using an unsupported Java runtime.
>
> process [50690]... waiting for server to be ready.neo4j-community-2.0.3/bin/neo4j: line 147:  lsof : command not found
>
> .neo4j-community-2.0.3/bin/neo4j: line 147: lsof : command not found
>
> .neo4j-community-2.0.3/bin/neo4j: line 147: lsof : command not found
>
> . Failed to start within 120 seconds.
>
> Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.

I checked for the solution for this and came to know that `/usr/sbin` had to be added to the path. On doing so and restarting the server, I got the following message

> Another server-process is running with [40903], cannot start a new one. Exiting.

However, when I run the command `neo4j staus` , it says

> Neo4j Server is not running

Can anybody please help me with how should I get started with it?

Comment: are you using CentOS? Because by default `lsof` command is not installed. you can install it by `yum install lsof` (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/1kini_GmVf8)

Answer (score 2):

This is very late, but might help others.
If it tells you this, and you check that process id with, for example, `ps aux | grep 40903`, and it's not neo4j, the problem might be that the port is being used.

By default neo4j uses 7474, but can change this on the neo4j folder `/conf/neo4j-server.properties` and that was my problem, I had set the port to '22' which was being used. SO make sure it is set to a port that is open and available.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to examine the startup script.

`Another server-process is running with [40903], cannot start a new one. Exiting.`

indicates (me to) that there might be a pid file (or the script uses them) which was written and is checked before attempting to start a new instances. This the normal thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to kill the other process using `kill`

You can see this answer for how to kill the process:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/when-should-i-not-kill-9-a-process

Otherwise, restarting the operating system will also do the job. For me, I normally start neo4j in the console, as in `./neo4j console`. This makes it easier to stop the process.